# I am trying a proper logic for stock managment

Tags: sql

I have a table StockManagement it looks like this

```
PId          Qty             Dateof Booking           DateOfReturning
1              5               1 Jan 2013               3 Jan 2013
1              5               1 Jan 2013               4 Jan 2012
```

Now let's suppose I have 10 quantity of Product A. As my table shows I had Issue 5 Product A from 1 JAn to 3 Jan And another 5 From 1 Jan to 4 Jan .Now My customer want to book Product A from 4 Jan to 7 Jan.As you can see in table the 5 Product A will be return on 3 Jan so I can issue 5 Product from 4 Jan. This is what I want to do through query.

So please help me to get the available quantity between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(s1.qty) from StockManagement s1 inner join
StockManagement s2 on s1.PId=s2.PId
where to_date(s1.DateofBooking,'dd/mm/yyyy') not 
between to_date(s2.DateofBooking,'dd/mm/yyyy') and 
to_date(s2.DateOfReturning,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Try this. meanwhile I will try to post you a live demo

[**SQL_LIVE_DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e41f1/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @BkDate datetime, @qty int, @Pid int
select @BkDate='04-Jan-2013', @qty=5, @Pid=1

select sum(Qty) AvailableQty 
from StockManagement 
where 
  Id=@Pid AND 
  @BkDate not between DateOfBooking and DateOfReturning
having sum(Qty)>=@qty
```

Comment: Might want to read Aaron Betrand's article on between [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)